# Validity of my weird proof that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-verification

On a recent linear algebra exam, I was required to prove that "for every $n \times k$ matrix $A$ and $k \times n$ matrix $B$ over the same field, it holds that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues except for 0."

This is a classic result and I really should have known better, but for some reason the only proof I could come up with is the following. It's kind of uncanny (the examiner rejected it), but I think it might be valid anyway. Am I correct?

---

**Proof:**

Let $M_{AB}(t)$ and $M_{BA}(t)$ be the minimal polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$ respectively.

It holds that:

$M_{AB}(AB)=0$.

Therefore:

$B \cdot M_{AB}(AB)=0$

$M_{AB}(BA) \cdot B=0$

$M_{AB}(BA) \cdot BA=0$

So we see that $BA$ is a zero of the polynomial $M_{AB}(t) \cdot t=0$.

Therefore, $M_{BA}(t)\: |\: M_{AB}(t)\,t$, which means that $M_{BA}(t)$ and $M_{AB}(t)$ share the same irreducible factors except possibly for $t$, and the claim follows. $\square$

---

**Please note:**

I know that this result has been addressed many times on this site, but I didn't find my proof anywhere, so I think this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Why $BM_{AB}(AB)=M_{AB}(BA)B$?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: $B(AB)^n = (BA)^nB$. The result follows.

Comment: Normally when the examiner rejects a proof, he should give an argument why he thinks the proof is insufficient or false.

Comment: The examiner did not say why it was wrong? There are certainly easier proofs, but this proof works. I'd have been more specific about why $BM(AB) = M(BA)B$, but it is a nice solution.

Comment: OK thanks everyone!! The examiner commented on a minor issue in the way I wrote out the proof in the exam, so he was right to take off some marks. I wanted to be sure the idea was correct before I talk to him about it because he gave me 0/25 points for it, suggesting the idea was flawed.

Comment: (Added: My comment repeats part of Thomas's answer.) Don't you also need to show (or mention) the reverse divisibility result, that $M_{AB}(t)|M_{BA}(t)t$? The one-way divisibility you stated doesn't show that the two minimal polynomials "share the same irreducible factors except possibly for $t$." It only shows that every nonzero eigenvalue of $BA$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$, but not vice versa. There's no additional cleverness needed, but the reverse does have to be stated, I think.

Comment: I suppose you should mention that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $C$ iff $m_{C}(\lambda)=0$, where $m_{C}$ is the minimal polynomial of $C$. That forces you to stay in the same field, too.

Comment: @Steve Kass, Thomas Andrews. Yes, you are right about the symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer looks correct. It's definitely more complicated than the standard proof.

You could spell out the reason that $BM_{AB}(AB)=M_{AB}(BA)B$, but it's actually clever. Not sure I'd call it "uncanny."

Oh, you also left out the symmetry part - that $M_{BA}(t)\mid M_{AB}(t)t$ and $M_{AB}(t)\mid M_{BA}(t)t$. That symmetry is needed to get that they share the same set of non-zero eigenvalues.